# How to filter records between two different dates Cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

This is the solution in SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM  exploits
WHERE  date
BETWEEN  '2014-01-01'
AND  '2014-12-31'
ORDER BY  exploits.date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

this my solution in **CakePhp** (been totally Newbi at this)

```
$exploits = $this->Exploit->find('all', array(
               'conditions' => array(
               'Exploit.date BETWEEN 2014-01-01 AND 2014-12-31')
            $this->set('exploits', $exploits);

    }
```

Thank you for the help

======

when trying the new code

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Before only this what i had 
`private function _index_action(){

```
    $exploits = $this->Exploit->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'is_published' => 1),
        'limit' => 6,
        'recursive' => -1,`
```

but I want to try to display only 6 elements between date... (sorry newbi and french :P)

Comment: apart from not using a limit or a sort order - the find call in the question would work (if it was valid php code, which as written it isn't). There are minor changes you can make the conditions, but is there something wrong with the result? if so what?

Comment: what error you are getting or explain your question

Comment: Your edit appears to have no bearing on the original question

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$exploits = $this->Exploit->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Exploit.date between ? and ?'=> array('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31'),
    ),
    'order' => array('date' => 'desc'),
    'limit'=>30
));
```

Comment: Great this work need to add this to display at then $this->set('exploits', $exploits);

Comment: THANK YOU ALL ! Merci 
Happy that quick answer and the help gang